# Zoom listener for PhotoView

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I'm using Chris Bane's [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) to display ImageViews in a ViewPager. I want to disable the ViewPager's scrolling when the user has zoomed into an image. I already found this [Hacky ViewPager](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/HackyViewPager.java) which can be used to enable/disable scrolling by calling toggleLock().

```
public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isLocked;

    public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        isLocked = false;
    }

    public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        isLocked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            try {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return !isLocked && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void toggleLock() {
        isLocked = !isLocked;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean isLocked) {
        this.isLocked = isLocked;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return isLocked;
    }

}
```

So my problem here is that I'm not sure at which point I have to call toogleLock(). I guess I have to implement a listener, but I'm not sure which one would be the best. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

EDIT: I figured it out on my own!

```
photoview.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rectF) {
                if (photoview.getScale() > 1) {
                    sPager.setLocked(true);
                } else {
                    sPager.setLocked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Good one, man! 
One note, though: checking photoview.getScale != 1 would cover the extra zoom-out when already in scale==1.
I was using this in a ViewPager and it was intercepting the zoom-out. This one should do the trick.

Comment: Hey, it's my first time using PhotoView. Is there any way to determine if the zooming out level has reached the maximum? @vchelbanster

Comment: @DanielReyhanian It's a matter of checking the source code: 
[PhotoViewAttacher.java](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/PhotoViewAttacher.java)

`private static float DEFAULT_MAX_SCALE = 3.0f;` This is the default maximum. Unless you change it with `setMaximumScale` method.

Answer (score 5):

For me, `photoview.getScale() == 1` always and I use the zoom.

The `scaleFactor` in `setOnScaleChangeListener` is only the scale at certain time independent of the previous value. We need to calculate the cumulative `scaleFactor` .

```
private float cumulScaleFactor = 1;

photoViewAttacher.setOnScaleChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnScaleChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void onScaleChange(final float scaleFactor, final float focusX, final float focusY) {
     cumulScaleFactor = cumulScaleFactor * scaleFactor;

     sPager.setLocked(isValueApproximate(1.0f, cumulScaleFactor));
 }
});


private boolean isValueApproximate(final float expectedValue, final float value) {
    final float errorMargin = 0.01f;
    return Math.abs(expectedValue - value) < errorMargin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using HackyViewPager I set photoview.setAllowParentInterceptOnEdge(true) , when photo Scale = 1.

```
photoView.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
    photoView.setAllowParentInterceptOnEdge(photoView.getScale() == 1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I joined @Mashmori and @Raymond Chenon anwsers and you get:

```
photoView.setOnMatrixChangeListener {
        val isZoomedOut = isValueApproximate(photoView.scale, 1f)
        photoView.setAllowParentInterceptOnEdge(isZoomedOut)
    }

private fun isValueApproximate(expectedValue: Float, value: Float): Boolean {
    val errorMargin = 0.01f
    return abs(expectedValue - value) < errorMargin
}
```